# How can a text changer be controlled with multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript

In the following example, I use a `text changer` that later has multiple arrays of text. I have to control this with the `next button`. It should be so that the text arrays can be changed over `next button`.

via `Subtitle Open` open the `text 1.1` and press `play, stop` or `reset`.Then the `test 2.1` should appear over the `next button`.

That does not really run. Can someone help me there? Many Thanks.

```js
var texter1 = new Array
    texter1[0]='Text 1.1';
    texter1[1]='Text 1.2';
    texter1[2]='';
    texter1[3]='Text 1.3';
    texter1[4]='Text 1.4';
    texter1[5]='Text 1.5';
    texter1[6]='';
    texter1[7]='End';
var i=0;

var texter2 = new Array
    texter2[0]='Text 2.1';
    texter2[1]='Text 2.2';
    texter2[2]='';
    texter2[3]='Text 2.3';
    texter2[4]='Text 2.4';
    texter2[5]='Text 2.5';
    texter2[6]='';
    texter2[7]='End';
var i1=0; 
 
function changer(){
    document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter1[i],texter2[i1];
  //document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter2[i];
    i++;
    i1++;
    if(i==texter1.length-1) i = 0;
    if(i1==texter2.length-1) i1 = 0;
}
 
var info = document.getElementById( "transbox" );  
    info.style.display = "none";                
 

function SubShow() {  
    info.style.display = "";
}

function SubHide() {  
    info.style.display = "none";
}
function SubStop() {  
    clearInterval( timerId ); 
}
function SubPlay() {  
    timerId = window.setInterval ( changer, 1500 );  
}
function SubReset() { 
    i = 0
    i1 = 0
    changer(); 
    clearInterval( timerId ); 
}
 
  
 
var currentArray = -1;
 
 
var previous = function previous( event ) {
currentArray -= 1;
if ( currentArray < 0 ) currentArray = changer.length - 1;
     renderArray( changer[ currentArray ] );
  
if ( currentArray == 0 ) {
     texter1();   
}  
if ( currentArray == 1 ) {   
     texter2();
} 
   
};


var next = function next( event ) {
currentArray += 1;  
if ( currentArray > changer.length - 1 ) currentArray = 0;
     renderArray( changer[ currentArray ] );  
  
if ( currentArray == 0 ) {
     texter1();   
}  
if ( currentArray == 1 ) {   
     texter2();
} 
 
};
```

```css
#transbox {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;   
    margin-top:50px;   
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="SubShow()">Subtitle Open</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SubHide()">Subtitle Close</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SubPlay()">Subtitle Play</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SubStop()">Subtitle Stop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="SubReset()">Subtitle Reset</button>

<input type="button" id="prev_button" value="<< Prev" onclick= "prev_button">
<input type="button" id="next_button" value="Next >>" onclick= "next_button">

<body onLoad="changer()">
  
<div id="transbox"></div>
```

Comment: in `next` and `previous` you use the variable `changer` like an array, but it's a function.

Comment: ***@James*** thanks for the answer, that would mean that only have to write `texter1`, without `();` ?

Comment: No of course not. `next and prev` are not working properly yet.

Comment: you should call methods from HTML with parenthesis: `prev_button()` and `next_button()`. I don't see these methods in the JS either

Comment: Yeah I see that your prev/next functions aren't hooked up yet.  I think the main problem is `document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter1[i],texter2[i1];` - I'm not sure what you expect that to do, but it will only display texter1[i] the way it is.  What do you want that line to do?

Comment: I have already tried a lot, but get no usable results. Maybe it will be useful if you see the whole context. Show this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189404/how-can-as-well-load-different-subtitles-with-the-other-files)